# When cleaning HVAC ducts, is treatment for fungi and bacteria routine and mandatory after 20 years?

Tags: hvac

Is treatment for fungi and bacteria routine and mandatory after 20 years? Or should we test for fungi or bacteria first? This would be in addition to air duct cleaning.

Comment: A test for bacteria in general seems silly since you're covered in it already. And it's almost certainly *not* mandatory in your own home. Given the silence to the question, I'd say it's not even routine. Sounds like an excessive up-sell to me.

Comment: I have not been impressed with air duct cleaning companies. Big upsale and the price was high to begin with.